# How do I get the time while playing youtube video?

Tags: iphone, ios, time, youtube

i want to calculate time when youtube video is being played, can any one tell me how to get this,i am using this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tblResourcesDetails deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    ChildrenDetailsDO *childDetailsDO = [listResourcesDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"url : %@", childDetailsDO.url);
    NSLog(@"ka_url : %@", childDetailsDO.ka_url);
    LBYouTubePlayerViewController* controller = [[LBYouTubePlayerViewController alloc] initWithYouTubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:childDetailsDO.url] quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationIncrementWatchedVideosCounter object:nil userInfo:nil];

    }];
```